# Is there any way to require an additional password to use sudo, or add a timed delay to sudo commands?

Tags: sudo

I edited the /etc/hosts file to block time-wasting websites because I have a problem with procrastinating, and I want to make it difficult to edit the file by making it a requirement to type in an additional password to be able to edit the /etc/hosts file, or by adding a delay before sudo commands execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `chattr` to change attributes and 'lsattr` to check the current attributes. See the description at this link

[File_attributes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes#File_attributes)

I suggest that you try the following command

```
sudo chattr +i /etc/hosts
```

which should make the file immutable (not possible to change) until you reset the immutable attribute with

```
sudo chattr -i /etc/hosts
```

---

You can check the attributes with

```
sudo lsattr /etc/hosts
```